# Vue project slows down more after every route

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**The Problem:**
Every time I navigate between the list page (home) and detail page my site starts to slow down drastically. With this I mean, after like 3 times going back and forth I start noticing it having hiccups, after 5-6 times my whole pc starts to freeze.

---

**My Project:**
It's a Vue Project, with currently only 2 routes. The homepage is a list of items and a detail page for every item on the list. The detail page (specifically the `tree component`) is probably where the issue is because when I remove this, the problem is gone. I put some code at the bottom of this post with the basic structure of the project.

---

**What I'm looking for:**
Since I'm not getting any errors, I'm not sure where the problem is here. There is probably something I can do better in the way my project is set up, the way I load/show things. So I'm looking for ways to find out where the problem is at.

---

**What I tried:**

1. Stay Alive
   While searching for solutions I came across the `<stay-alive>` tag. I tried putting this around my `<router-view>`. This does get rid of the slowing down, but I also lose all my dynamic content. The data on all pages is now the same when I navigate between different detail pages.
2. Data Fetching (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation)
   I was thinking, maybe it helps if I load all the data before someone enters a route or do some kind of loading before I show the page. This did not help.

It's possible that one of these things is the right direction, and I just didn't implement it right. Not 100% confident with my coding yet :)

**views/home.vue**
Just a simple page with a list of items that link to the detail page

```
<template>
  // list with items that link to their corresponding detail page
</template>

import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'builds'
    ])
  }
}
```

**views/details.vue**
Now, this page is a little more complex. The big thing on this page is a canvas that is generated with Pixi Js, this canvas changes while the user is scrolling through the page. The Canvas element is its own component, so I pass some data with a prop.

```
<template>
  <div class='page-wrapper'>
    <div class="content-container">
      <section class="level milestone" v-for="level in build.guide" :key="level.id" :id="level.level">
        // Some stuff to display
      </section>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <tree :myprop="current"></tree>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import Tree from '@/components/tree'

export default {
  name: 'Build',
  watch: {
    currentActive: {
      // To know where to user currently is
      // Pass this data to my tree component
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'builds'
    ])
  }
}
```

**components/tree.vue**
This is where my canvas is drawn with the help of data from a JSON file.

```
<template>
  <div id="tree">
  </div>
</template>

import axios from 'axios'
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'
import { Viewport } from 'pixi-viewport'

export default {
  name: 'Tree',
  props: ['myprop'],
  data () {
    return {
      app: new PIXI.Application({ transparent: true, antialias: true }),
      treeData: {},
      // Some more
    }
  },
  watch: {
    myprop: function (newVal) {
      // Some stuff with my prop
    }
  },
  created () {
    axios.get('/data/data.json', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        this.treeData = response.data
        this.loadTree()
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  },
  methods: {
    loadTree () {
      // Load images and draw the canvas
      PIXI.loader
        .add('Image', require('@/assets/image.png'))
        .load(this.drawTree)
    },
    drawTree () {
      // Do all the drawing on the canvas
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: its likely something to do with your backend data loading / Pixi

Comment: agreed, potentially, try to open an network developer tools and check the api call. There could be a bubbling of calls out there

Comment: Ah, yes. When i look at my Network tab i can see my data.json multiple times after i navigated back and forth a few times. So, somehow i need to cache this data or something? Just had a quick look at https://github.com/kuitos/axios-extensions, but doesn't seem to do the job. Going to play/look around a little more. If you guys have any tips in what direction to look, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Oke, so i've kind of solved it for now. I'm still new to all this, but i started to look more into working with dev tools so i can find out where issues like this come from. I think i still can win a lot with this, but for now it helped to destroy my PIXI app from data when i'm done with it.

```
  beforeDestroy () {
    this.app.destroy()
  }
```

Maybe some usefull links if someone ever finds this thread that has similar issues:

**Using dev tools to find memory leaks:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr2vrhrNaRo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJRbZdtKmxU

**Avoiding memory leaks in vue:**
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html